# proof -divergence series

Tags: functions, continuity

[image: I know that the series 1/n and -1/2n is divergent but how do i prove it?]

I know that the series 1/n and -1/2n is divergent but how do i prove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill in the details but the main steps are (i) combine two subsequent terms $$\frac{1}n{}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}=\frac{n+2}{2n(n+1)}$$ (ii) Note that in terms of the original  sequence $S_n$ of partial sums, what you did in the previous part was take a subsequence $T_n$. (iii) Show that Your new series diverges by the limit comparison test with the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ Since your new series diverges , 
i.e. $i.e.$ its sequence of partial sums $T_n$ diverges, so does the sequence $S_n.$ Thus the original series diverges.